# WCF Data Services ODATA

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf-data-services, odata

I am working on WCF Data Services. I have a function in my service which adds a record into a table in SQL DB and return the ID of the Inserted record.

I Used to Pass the values to be inserted in the form of Parameters to the Function.

For Example

```
 public int Add(string Name, string Password)
 {
      // Here I will Add the record and return the ID of the record added in DB
 }
```

But I dont want to do this way of passing in the form of parameters.

I want to pass the object directly.

Like

```
public int Add(User user)
{
    // Here I will Add the record and return the ID of the record added in DB
}
```

I wrote the function like above in my services and my services project is successfull. When I update my ServiceRefrences I get **Error**.

> It says only primitive types are supported. Is there any work around
>   this problem.

Thanks For Your Time in Answering my Question.

Comment: Thanks Anand will start doing that. Actually I am not familiar with using stack overflow. Thanks for your advice. I will be doing that from now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF Data Services (and OData protocol for that matter) only support passing primitive values as parameters to service operations.

The OData way of adding a new entity into an entity set is to send a POST with the entity in the payload to the entity set URL. In the WCF DS Service this will get translated into several calls to the IUpdatable interface on your context.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain or if you have a link to share.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking for... hopefully this will help: http://www.odata.org/documentation/operations#CreatingnewEntries. And possibly this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723653.aspx

Comment: Sorry for Confusion. I want to add an entity to entityset in the service by passing the object of the entity directly as parameter to service operation. From your answer and bit of r & d I found that only prmitives types are supported as parameters to service operations.

Comment: Yes - only primitive types are supported as parameters. As noted above the recommended way to add entity to an entity set is to send a POST request to the entity set URL.